# Font Awesome Icons resize when adjusting screen size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a footer including social media icons from Font Awesome. When I resize the desktop size (for tablet or mobile screen), the Icons start getting smaller, which I don't want.

Can anyone help me with this problem? This would be very appreciated.

```
 [1]: https://codepen.io/Emen/pen/zyJeZK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give font-size in px.. that will fix your prob.

Comment: that is the solution!! Thanks a lot for your quick help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .your-icon-class {

    }
}
```

[watch here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior because the font icons are tied to the i tag, which are effected by CSS font-size.

What you need to do, when you make your font adjustments for mobile also tweak the font-size of your icons, most likely by targeting the i tag.